# Google Apps Script: How to retrieve values of dynamically named objects from Yahoo Finance

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to pull raw data from dynamically named objects from Yahoo Finance.  In the following simplified example codes, I hard coded its object key name and index after manually checking its object structure to retrieve raw data.  Instead of such a hard coding which will be really difficult if more than 100 keys, I'm looking for a smart solution that checks all the object keys and pull their raw data from them directly without needing to write each key names manually.  How can I do that?  Thanks!

My expected output:

[image]

```
function test() {

  var url = 'https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/ws/fundamentals-timeseries/v1/finance/timeseries/AVGO?lang=en-US&region=US&symbol=AVGO&padTimeSeries=true&type=annualInterestExpense,trailingInterestExpense&merge=false&period1=493590046&period2=1672807102&corsDomain=finance.yahoo.com';
  var obj = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { muteHttpExceptions: true }).getContentText();
  obj = JSON.parse(obj);  //Convert strings to object

  var type = obj.timeseries.result.map(({ meta: { type } }) => type).flat();
  console.log(type)

  var trailingInterestExpenseRAW = obj.timeseries.result[0].trailingInterestExpense.map(({ reportedValue: { raw } }) => raw);
  var annualInterestExpenseRAW = obj.timeseries.result[1].annualInterestExpense.map(({ reportedValue: { raw } }) => raw);
  console.log(['trailingInterestExpense', ...trailingInterestExpenseRAW],
    ['annualInterestExpense', ...annualInterestExpenseRAW])
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var type = obj.timeseries.result.map(({ meta: { type } }) => type).flat();
console.log(type)

var trailingInterestExpenseRAW = obj.timeseries.result[0].trailingInterestExpense.map(({ reportedValue: { raw } }) => raw);
var annualInterestExpenseRAW = obj.timeseries.result[1].annualInterestExpense.map(({ reportedValue: { raw } }) => raw);
console.log(['trailingInterestExpense', ...trailingInterestExpenseRAW],
  ['annualInterestExpense', ...annualInterestExpenseRAW])
```

#### To:

```
var types = obj.timeseries.result.flatMap(({ meta: { type } }) => type);
var array = obj.timeseries.result.map(o => types.flatMap(type => o[type] ? [type, ...o[type].map(({ reportedValue: { raw } }) => raw)] : []));
var maxLen = Math.max(...array.map(r => r.length));
var values = array.map(r => [...r, ...Array(maxLen - r.length).fill(null)]);
console.log(values); // You can see the values in the log.

// In this sample, the values are put to the active sheet.
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
```

- When this script is run, `values` is `[["trailingInterestExpense",1737000000,null,null,null],["annualInterestExpense",1444000000,1777000000,1885000000,1737000000]]`. By this, this value can be put to the sheet using `setValues`.

#### References:

- [flatMap()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: many thanks again!  After spending a few hours unsuccessfully to figure out, I ended up asking here.  What a magic codes!

Comment: Hi @Tanaike I have another challenge when the obj has a key but without 'reportedValue' property, causing error.   In order to skip any key without 'reportedValue' property,  what should be modified  in your "var array = obj.timeseries.result.map(o => types.flatMap(type => o[type] ? [type, ...o[type].map(({ reportedValue: { raw } }) => raw)] : []));"    Thank you again!

Comment: @Newbie About your new question of `I have another challenge when the obj has a key but without 'reportedValue' property, causing error. In order to skip any key without 'reportedValue' property, what should be modified in your "var array = obj.timeseries.result.map(o => types.flatMap(type => o[type] ? [type, ...o[type].map(({ reportedValue: { raw } }) => raw)] : []));" Thank you again!`, I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your new question. Can I ask you about the detail of your new question?

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, if you run this url with your code, you can understand my problem.  Because the url is too long, I'm adding another comment only with its url.

Comment: https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/ws/fundamentals-timeseries/v1/finance/timeseries/CRWD?lang=en-US&region=US&symbol=CRWD&padTimeSeries=true&type=annualTaxProvision,trailingTaxProvision,annualPretaxIncome,trailingPretaxIncome,annualInterestExpenseNonOperating,trailingInterestExpenseNonOperating,annualLongTermDebt,quarterlyLongTermDebt,annualCurrentDebt,quarterlyCurrentDebt,annualCashCashEquivalentsAndShortTermInvestments,quarterlyCashCashEquivalentsAndShortTermInvestments,annualFreeCashFlow,trailingFreeCashFlow&merge=false&period1=493590046&period2=1672980169&corsDomain=finance.yahoo.com

Comment: @Newbie Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, from `if you run this url with your code, you can understand my problem. Because the url is too long, I'm adding another comment only with its url.`, I cannot still understand your new question. But I would like to support you. So, can you post it as a new question by including more information? By this, I would like to try to understand your new question. If you can cooperate to resolve your new question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?